# EclipseLink / JPA: How to programmatically get the number of SQL queries that have been performed

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink, sniffy

I'm using JPA, by way of EclipseLink. In my unit tests, I'd like to test how many SQL queries were performed during an operation. That way, if a later modification causes the query count to explode (if lazy loading is triggered, for instance), the unit test will flag it as potentially needing optimization.

I'm striking out in finding the correct API to do this. A pure-JPA solution would be ideal, but I'm fine with using EclipseLink-specific APIs in my unit tests. I looked at the EclipseLink profiler, but it doesn't seem to give me a way to count the number of SQL queries.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Could you not just execute all of your queries through some class that keeps count? Or am I missing something in the description?

Comment: @Cruncher That would be extremely difficult to keep track of across an entire JPA implementation since you could have tens (or hundreds) of Entity objects that are all being persisted. Since most JPAs perform a bit of "magic" as well (i.e. smart caching), you would have to do some digging to get an actual count of queries.

Comment: @Cruncher In my case most of the queries are being performed behind-the-scenes when lazily-fetched foreign entities are referenced. That's why I'd like to add the test: If I make a change (such as accessing a child entity I wasn't before) that causes the query count to increase, I want the test to catch it so that I can take the appropriate action - modifying the test (if the increase in queries is acceptable), changing the fetch on that class from lazy to eager, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find a proper tool for such validation and created my own. It is called [sniffy](http://sniffy.io/) and available under MIT license.

You can assert the number of generated queries like shown below:

```
// Integrate Sniffy to your test using @Rule annotation and a QueryCounter field
@Rule
public final QueryCounter queryCounter = new QueryCounter();

// Now just add @Expectation or @Expectations annotations to define number of queries allowed for given method
@Test
@Expectation(1)
public void testJUnitIntegration() throws SQLException {
    // Just add sniffer: in front of your JDBC connection URL in order to enable sniffer
    final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("sniffer:jdbc:h2:mem:", "sa", "sa");
    // Do not make any changes in your code - just add the @Rule QueryCounter and put annotations on your test method
    connection.createStatement().execute("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
}
```

More information about integration with JUnit available in [project wiki](https://github.com/sniffy/sniffy/wiki/JUnit)

Answer (score 2):

Most databases have built-in statistics, you might consider using those.

E.g. MySQL has SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Queries' command which dumps total amount of queries run.

Comment: Interesting idea - thanks. Though the JUnit tests are using in-memory HSQLDB, and I'm striking out looking for a similar feature in the HSQL docs.

Answer (score 0):

Sniffy looks like a nice tool and maybe I will give it try in a future.

Below you can find how to handle profiling using only eclipseLink.
Whole code can be found [here](https://github.com/ssledz/learning/blob/master/eclipse-link-playground/src/main/scala/io/github/ssledz/JpaQueryProfilingExample.scala)

```
import io.github.ssledz.domain.{Employee, Project}
import javax.persistence.{EntityManagerFactory, Persistence, PersistenceUnitUtil}
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.BatchFetchType
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate
import org.eclipse.persistence.queries.LoadGroup
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.SessionProfiler
import org.eclipse.persistence.tools.profiler.PerformanceMonitor

import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

/**
 * This example requires that all entities are properly waved by eclipseLink
 *
 * In order to make eclipseLink happy download java agent
 * wget -O /tmp/eclipselink.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.7.7/eclipselink-2.7.7.jar
 * pass following parameter -javaagent:/tmp/eclipselink.jar to jvm
 * and set 'eclipselink.weaving' to true in persistance.xml
 *
 */
object JpaQueryProfilingExample extends App {

  val emf: EntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default")
  val pUtil: PersistenceUnitUtil = emf.getPersistenceUnitUtil
  val emfd: EntityManagerFactoryDelegate = emf.unwrap(classOf[EntityManagerFactoryDelegate])
  val profiler: PerformanceMonitor = emfd.getServerSession.getProfiler.asInstanceOf[PerformanceMonitor]

  val em = emf.createEntityManager()

  clearDb()

  val johny = createEmployee("Johny", "Bravo", "eclipse-link-playground")
  val tom = createEmployee("Tom", "Tip", "eclipse-link-profiling")

  em.clear()
  emf.getCache.evictAll()

  val stats = QueryStatistics(profiler)

  val employees = findAll()

  def numberOfDbQueries: Int = QueryStatistics(profiler).diff(stats).numberOfDbQueries

  assert(employees.size == 2)
  assert(numberOfDbQueries == 1)

  assertNotLoaded(employees.head, "projects")

  employees.foreach(_.getProjects) // trigger lazy loading

  assert(numberOfDbQueries == 3, "+2 for lazy loaded project")

  private def clearDb(): Unit = {
    val tx = em.getTransaction
    tx.begin()
    em.createQuery("delete from Employee").executeUpdate()
    em.createQuery("delete from Project").executeUpdate()
    tx.commit()
  }

  private def findAll(): List[Employee] =
    em.createQuery("select e from Employee e", classOf[Employee]).getResultList.asScala.toList

  private def findAllWithProjects(): List[Employee] = {
    val query = em.createQuery("select e from Employee e", classOf[Employee])
    query.setHint(QueryHints.LOAD_GROUP, loadGroup("projects"))
    query.setHint(QueryHints.BATCH_TYPE, BatchFetchType.EXISTS)
    query.setHint(QueryHints.BATCH, "e.projects")
    query.getResultList.asScala.toList
  }

  private def createEmployee(firstName: String, lastName: String, projectName: String): Employee = {
    val employee = new Employee
    employee.setFirstName(firstName)
    employee.setLastName(lastName)
    val project = employee.addProject(Project(projectName))
    val tx = em.getTransaction
    tx.begin()
    em.persist(employee)
    em.persist(project)
    tx.commit()
    employee
  }

  private def loadGroup(attributes: String*): LoadGroup = {
    val lg = new LoadGroup()
    attributes.foreach(lg.addAttribute)
    lg
  }

  private def assertLoaded(obj: AnyRef, attributeName: String): Unit = assertLoadedOrNot(obj, attributeName, true)

  private def assertNotLoaded(obj: AnyRef, attributeName: String): Unit = assertLoadedOrNot(obj, attributeName, false)

  private def assertLoadedOrNot(obj: AnyRef, attributeName: String, loaded: Boolean): Unit = {
    val message = s"$attributeName property should be ${if (loaded) "eagerly" else "lazy"} loaded"
    assert(pUtil.isLoaded(obj, attributeName) == loaded, s"because $message")
  }

}

case class QueryStatistics(readAllQuery: Int, readObjectQuery: Int, cacheHits: Int) {

  def numberOfDbQueries: Int = (readObjectQuery + readAllQuery) - cacheHits

  def diff(other: QueryStatistics): QueryStatistics =
    QueryStatistics(
      readAllQuery - other.readAllQuery,
      readObjectQuery - other.readObjectQuery,
      cacheHits - other.cacheHits
    )
}

object QueryStatistics {
  def nullToZero(a: Any): Int = Option(a).map(_.toString.toInt).getOrElse(0)

  def apply(pm: PerformanceMonitor): QueryStatistics =
    new QueryStatistics(
      nullToZero(pm.getOperationTimings.get("Counter:ReadAllQuery")),
      nullToZero(pm.getOperationTimings.get("Counter:ReadObjectQuery")),
      nullToZero(pm.getOperationTimings.get(SessionProfiler.CacheHits))
    )
}
```

persistance.xml

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>io.github.ssledz.domain.Employee</class>
        <class>io.github.ssledz.domain.Project</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <!-- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#CACDCCEG2  -->
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.profiler" value="PerformanceMonitor"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="ALL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
<!--            <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger"/>-->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eclipse_link_test?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```